# getTimezoneOffset() with DayLightSaving

Tags: javascript, timezone

Is there a way to have this function return the timezone offset by taking into account the Daylight saving?

For example, we are in Romania, 2 hours before GMT (London time). But this function returns -180 (-3 hours) instead of -120 (-2 hours).

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettimezoneoffset.asp

Thank you,
George Pecherle

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/58728/JavaScript-code-to-determine-when-DayLight-Savings, it sounds to me you're looking for something similar to that. If not let me know and I'll try to help a bit more.